Connecting to a h2 database replaces the .mv.db file with a blank
I've converted h2-2.1.214.jar using ikvmc but everytime i point to a embedded (local) database, it auto creates a new one and replaces the existing .mv.db with a new db.
I've tested the same exact connection string using h2 console and it has successfully opened it.
Does anyone have any suggestions
Connection string:
jdbc:h2:C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Data\mydb
